# Generics: Compiler seems incapable of recognizing that the type passed to an argument is the same as what is returned - why?

Tags: java, generics, type-bounds

Let's say I have several POJOs which all extend a common supertype, `BaseObject`.

I have a `GenericDao` which is declared as `public interface GenericDao<T>`.

For each type-specific DAO, I have an interface which extends the generic type and restricts it to a concrete type (`public interface UserDao extends GenericDao<User>`) and then an implementation of the type-specific DAO.

In a class that attempts to use a number of `GenericDao` implementations, I have a method that looks like

```
public <T extends BaseObject> long create(T object) {
    return getDao(object.getClass()).save(object);
}
```

If I implement `getDao()` so that it's parameter is a `Class` object, such as

```
private <T extends BaseObject> GenericDao<T> getDao(Class<T> clazz) { ... }
```

Then the call to `getDao(object.getClass()` in the `create()` method fails to compile - the compiler appears to interpret the return type of `getDao()` as

```
GenericDao<? extends BaseContractObject>
```

rather than recognizing that `getDao(Class<T>)` is going to return me a `GenericDao` of the same type `T`.

Can someone explain why this is? I understand that repeated appearances of the same type bound or wildcard don't necessary refer to the same type; however it seems like the compiler should recognize from the signature of `getDao(Class<T>)` that the T passed in should be the same T returned (but obviously it isn't capable of recognizing this, the *why* is the part I fail to grasp).

If I instead define `getDao`'s signature to be

```
private <T extends BaseContractObject> GenericDao<T> getDao(T obj) { ... }
```

Then there is no issue in compiling a `create()` implementation which looks like

```
public <T extends BaseContractObject> long create(T object) {
    return getDao(object).save(object);
}
```

So why is the compiler capable of recognizing in this case that the `T` argument passed to `getDao(T)` is the same `T` in the return type, whereas it couldn't recognize this when the argument was `Class<T>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `object.getClass()`, where object is of type `T extends BaseObject`, returns a `Class<? extends BaseObject>`, not a `Class<T>` as one might expect. So, `getDao()` is returning a DAO of the same type it receives; it's just not receiving the expected type.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks. I forgot that getClass() will return a wildcard type

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic type erasure issue.  `getClass()` has the following signature:

```
public final native Class<? extends Object> getClass();
```

If you have a `String` and do a `getClass()` on it, the class you get is `Class<? extends String>`.  The javadocs read:

```
 * @return The <code>java.lang.Class</code> object that represents
 *         the runtime class of the object.  The result is of type
 *         {@code Class<? extends X>} where X is the
 *         erasure of the static type of the expression on which
 *         <code>getClass</code> is called.
```

You will need to force the following cast to get it to work:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>)object.getClass();
return getDao(clazz).save(object);
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should explain why the constraint is not doing what you expect:

http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ206

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't answer the question. I'm not attempting to access `T.class`; my question is why the compiler doesn't recognize that the type bound `<T extends BaseObject>` means that the `T` in my input parameter `Class<T>` will refer to the same type as the `T` in the return type `GenericDao<T>`.